building pick and place gantry robot using ros2
I have been assigned to build a pick and place gantry robot. I am fresh mechanical engineer who just come out college. I have trying to get this ros2 stuff into my head, From various resources like Ros2 official documentation, Udemy and YouTube. I have got to know about basic like ros2_pakages, urdfs, gazebo, ros2control, rviz2
yet. I don't have fair idea about how I am going to build that robot using all these. Also, I am able to have those concepts as long I follow the tutorials, but when I try to work on my project, I become stagnant.
If it would be great, if someone can guide me through the process of building.
